# Excel page becomes too wide in LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

I saved a page of Excel to LibreOffice. However the page seems wider than the page on screen. When I print it loses part of the last column.
Any ideas where I am going wrong and, more importantly, how to fix it, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust two things to solve your problem:

- print margins (File > Print Preview / Settings > Margins)
- cell width (reduce one of cells so it will fit within page margins)